# Alertmanager can't send email when running in Openshift (Error: getsockopt: connection timed out)

Tags: email, openshift, prometheus

I have Alertmanager and Prometheus running in Openshift. Alertmanager receives and shows the alerts from Prometheus but when sending it with any smtp server (I'm using Gmail now but I tried others), I get the following error:

> time="2017-05-30T08:47:21Z" level=error msg="Notify for 1 alerts failed: dial tcp 74.125.206.109:587: getsockopt: connection timed out" source="dispatch.go:261"

I have a `config.yml` which worked when I tried it locally with alertmanager and prometheus. I received the email alerts, so I dont get why it doesn't work when running in Openshift. I ran out of ideas.

**My config file:**

```
global:
      smtp_smarthost: 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
      smtp_from: 'emailtestingxxx@gmail.com'
      smtp_auth_username: 'emailtestingxxx@gmail.com'
      smtp_auth_password: 'ABCD1234'

    templates: 
    - '/etc/alertmanager/template/*.tmpl'

      group_by: ['alertname', 'cluster', 'service']
      group_wait: 1m
      group_interval: 1m
      repeat_interval: 1m 

      receiver: team-X-mails
      routes:

      - match:
          severity: page
        receiver: team-X-mails
    receivers:
    - name: 'team-X-mails'
      email_configs:
      - to: 'myemail@myemail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was a firewall configuration which was blocking the outgoing requests.